# Refresh view with display and setNeedsDisplay not working

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I am having problems updating my customView object during simulation. The window pops up after the simulation is done. I would like it to update itself during the simulation. For this I use `setNeedsDisplay:YES` and I have also tried `display`. None of this works for me however. Does anyone have an idea how I should get this working? As you can see below I have tried to create a new thread for the updating as well as using NSOperations. Grateful for help!

```
//Run simulation
    for (int iteration=0; iteration<numberOfIterations; iteration++){
        //NSInvocationOperation *update = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(updatePopulation) object:nil];
        //NSInvocationOperation *draw = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:view selector:@selector(redraw) object:nil];
        //[draw addDependency:update];
        //[queue addOperation:update];
        //[queue addOperation:draw];
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.01]; //to make it easer to see..
        [self updatePopulation];
        //[view redraw];
        [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(redraw) toTarget:view withObject:nil];
        //[self performSelector:@selector(updatePopulation) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
        //[view performSelector:@selector(redraw) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
        //Save segregation
        if (iteration%(numberOfIterations/100) == 0) {
            printf("hej\n");
        }
    }
```

in my viewer class:

```
- (void) redraw {
    //[self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
    [self display];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to do the painting on the worker thread.

This is not, as far as I am aware, supported.

To solve this, you need to move your simulation to a worker thread, and then use [performSelectorOnMainThread:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to invoke the redraw on the main thread. I find [this article on threading in cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafetySummary/ThreadSafetySummary.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH12-SW1) to be required reading when trying to implemented threaded cocoa apps.

Comment: That solved it! Thanks man! Did not now the relation between the different threads. Is it correct that the UI only reacts on the main thread? Thanks again,

Comment: While all threads have a run loop, its only the main thread that collects and dispatches NSEvents - which are what drive the input and output of NSWindows and NSViews.